# Glitch in the loops. Iterates only once irrespective of the count

Tags: java, loops

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

 Picture pictObj = new Picture("C:\\caterpillar.jpg");
 pictObj.swapRGB(2);
 pictObj.show();
}

public void swapRGB(){
  Pixel[] pixelArray = this.getPixels();
  Pixel pixel = null;
  int old_green = 0;
  int old_blue = 0;
  int old_red = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < pixelArray.length;i++){
      pixel = pixelArray[i];
      old_green = pixel.getGreen();
      old_blue = pixel.getBlue();
      old_red = pixel.getRed();
      pixel.setRed(old_green);
      pixel.setGreen(old_blue);
      pixel.setBlue(old_red);
  }
}

public void swapRGB(int numswaps) {
    Pixel[] pixelArray = this.getPixels();
    Pixel pixel = null;
    int old_green = 0;
    int old_blue = 0;
    int old_red = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while(count < numswaps) {
        for(int i = 0; i < pixelArray.length; i++) {
                pixel = pixelArray[i];
                //getting the green, red and blue value of the pixels
                old_green = pixel.getGreen();
                old_blue = pixel.getBlue();
                old_red = pixel.getRed(); 
                //Swapping Values of colors
                pixel.setRed(old_green);
                pixel.setGreen(old_blue);
                pixel.setBlue(old_red);
                pixel = pixelArray[i];
                count ++;
            }
        }
```

This program changes the color of the pixels in a picture; it swaps the red, green, blue values. My problem is, it just happens once irrespective of the number of the value of numswaps. 
If I call the function swapRGB() or swapRGB(numswaps) twice it changes colors, but that is not how I want the change in colors to happen, it should chnage according to the the number of numswaps.
Both the functions swapRGB() and swapRGB(numswaps) are in the same class.

Thank You.

Comment: `while(count < numswaps){` Twice Why?

Comment: my bad. I accidentally added that, while formatting code on here. It's not part of the code.

Comment: Can you add the code (or the interface) of class Pixel ?

Comment: I tried, but that requires too much formatting(it is a huge class that I had to download from my college website which you don't have access to), sorry.

Comment: What does your `getPixels` method do? My guess is that if you are only getting one iteration, then your pixelArray is only being given one value.

Comment: it returns a 1D array of pixels. Question has been solved; I incremented count in the wrong location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment.

You could change `swapRGB(int numswaps)` to do this:

```
public void swapRGB(int numswaps) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numswaps; ++i) {
        swapRGB();
    }
}
```

It's a lot less code, and it will also mean you only need to get `swapRGB()` working as you want it.

Comment: This works fine, but could you tell me what's the mistake I've made.

Comment: You are incrementing `count` in the inner loop (`for (i = ...`), so by the time this loop finishes, `count` will (presumably) be much bigger than `numswaps` and the outer `while` loop will exit.

Comment: You are right. I incremented the count in the wrong location!